# How do I reference the same schema for both GET and POST requests in OpenAPI 3 if the schema has other references

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have the following OpenAPI 3 schema:

```
{
  ...,
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "User": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Report": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          "user": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if I specify the GET requests for both User and Report everything looks good. The POST request for User is also working. However, the POST request for Report does not work. The body for the Report POST request should look like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

So the "name" property should not be specified since it is only a reference to a user that already exists and will be matched based on the id.

Is it possible to write the Report POST request so it understands that only the id of the user should be specified? Or am I forced to create two different Report schemas, one for the GET request and one for the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can approach this problem. You can either create a definition exclusively for POST, or split your `User` definition into more atomic components for reuse.

### Option 1: Multiple Definitions

Construct your Report `user` definition to something like this:

```
"user": {
  "id": {
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int64",
    "readOnly": true
  }
}
```

This has the benefit of being quick and easy, with no impact on other areas of your defnition. But this lends itself to a lot of code duplication, and any future changes to your design will require you to make sure you don't miss any of these special definitions.

### Option 2: Split and Reuse Your Definitions

You have a two distinct properties that have different uses, that are used in multiple definitions. This is a good candidate for a ref. Split up your `User` definition into multiple schemas. Something like this:

```
"schemas": {
  "userId": {
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int64",
    "readOnly": true
  },
  "userName": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "User": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/userId"
      },
      "name": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/userName"
      }
    }
}
```

This allows you to reuse the `userId` in your `Report` with the same definition of what an `id` actually is. This approach can start getting hard to read as you start growing your definitions into a larger API, but is far more maintainable as your API changes shape over time. Note that this also helps to define the difference between a User ID and a Report ID, which, while sharing the same name, likely hold different data and may have divergent rules over time.